# Does MySQL InnoDB engine use tablecache?

Tags: mysql, innodb

Does MySQL InnoDB engine use tablecache?  I migrated from MyIsam to Innodb as the table engine and the monitors for "table-cache" hitrate are super low.  Does Innodb use table-cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, the table cache is generally used for MyISAM tables. InnoDB has its own cache, called either the "data dictionary" or the "table definition cache". It's built-in and configures itself.

Answer (score 2):

No, InnoDB has it's own table cache which is per table.  They call it the 'data dictionary'